# Rewrite rule for a url conatining space in its end in web.config?

Tags: rewrite, asp.net

I am working on a rewriting process. I have been stuck on a point that.

```
<rule name="Uk3" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^activities/exploring/tours/tabid/3422/id/5205/k/([a-z0-9A-Z-\s]+)/p/1/nickis-beach-rides.aspx$" ignoreCase="true" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(www.)?abc.co.uk$" />            
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="/activities/exploring/tours.aspx" />
    </rule>
```

what does the above rule is doing:

It matches "activities/exploring/tours/tabid/3422/id/5205/k/" as it is and the it may contain anything after this upto "/p/1/nickis-beach-rides.aspx". It is working fine for all URLs except the following :

```
http://www.abc.co.uk/activities/exploring/tours/tabid/3422/id/5205/k/enjoy%20your%20morning%20cofee%20and%20evening%20cocktails%20on%20/p/1/nickis-beach-rides.aspx
```

which contains "enjoy%20your%20morning%20cofee%20and%20evening%20cocktails%20on%20" space as the last character that cause to stop this rule to work,

Anyone has any idea how can i add the above URL to work accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

I may be wrong, but i suspect that the culprit is more the `%` sign than the trailing space.

This `%` sign is not handled by your actual regex.

You could try : `([%a-z0-9A-Z-\s]+)`

Comment: @raman Does it help ?